# Finding Dll Function Parameters

Tags: function, dll, parameters, name-decoration

How can I find the parameters of an *undocumented* Dll function?

I have searched all over the internet and ended up finding one way: it involves decorated functions. However, I cannot find a way to get those.

*Any help would be appreciated.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to disassemble the application using, as Paul noted, something like IDA Pro (or the free version of the same).

A good introductory resource is the Wikibook, [x86 Disassembly](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly). Specifically, take a look at the section on [functions and stack frames](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Functions_and_Stack_Frames). Deducing function parameters can be straightforward for simple functions taking a few parameters of standard type.

Probably the best way to get started with this sort of thing is to create a small test DLL, create a few functions with known parameters, and then disassemble your DLL to see the patterns. Learn disassembly from your own functions (for which you have the source code and know the full signature) rather than plunging into disassembling third-party stuff.

Comment: Hrm.... As per my answer :P (joking ok;), anyhow you do not need to disassemble at all, you can get much more accurate information much faster before resorting to this, in fact this is the last possible resort after the steps I suggested.

Answer (score 10):

I did a fairly in-depth answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919051/finding-undocumented-apis-in-windows/1073361#1073361), ReactOS is your best bet as it seems again, *everybody* here is a bit off base.

I would **strongly discourage** attempting to disassemble system DLL's.

A **MUCH** more adventagious (and I do not believe discussed so far from the looks of things), technique is to enumerate the contents of PDB's.

PDB files are debug symbols as you may know, however, Microsoft is required, due to the action from anti-trust court cases, to release great volumes of otherwise un-documented information.

Fully accurate, usable and updated information for massive amount's of the Windows API is **only** documented via PDB file's.  The calling convention, argument count and even argument types and names are documented their (however not the specifics regarding the use of course:).

Review the DIA SDK, dia2dump is a good example distributed with Visual Studio, to investigate further, it also provides a solution to undecorate function's, to speak specifically to your question.

Also, kernel32 provides UnDecorateSymbolName, so you can use that also if you do not wish to link to the debug sdk libraries.

Answer (score 5):

The only way to do this is by disassembling the function and seeing how it uses the registers and stack. IDA Pro is the best tool to do this, but it's not something that is trivial.

Answer (score 4):

Is it COM Dll? If it is a COM Dll, then register it, use OLE view to know the Interafaces and parameters.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, download [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and open your DLL in it. You will see symbols exported and imported. If your function name looks like _MyFunction - it is "C" style (not decorated) and you have not too much to do with it (may be disassemble as said before)

If it is more like ?_MyFunction@LoNgSetOfSome@_StrangeChAracTers it is C++ - decorated and you may try to "undecorate" it using {unofficial} info from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B_Name_Mangling)

Comment: PE Explorer is able to internally unmangle the exported symbols from libraries compiled with both Microsoft and Borland C++ compilers: http://www.heaventools.com/unmangle.htm

Answer (score 1):

If the only piece of information you have is the undecorated function name, then unfortunately it's not possible to deduce the function parameters from that alone.

If you're good with assembly it might be possible to disassemble the machine code for the function and reverse engineer it. But that's reasonably hard to do for all but the simplest functions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really familiar with the PE format that Windows uses, but I'm pretty sure there is no real easy way to do this. If the symbol table has not been stripped you may be able to find some information (not sure how Windows stores debugging information in PE) but it almost certainly wouldn't help you with parameter types. The best thing to do is load the DLL into a debugger and experiment with it... monitor the raw memory on the stack frames, send various variable types, etc.

Even if you find a good resource on the debugging information in a PE file, there almost certainly won't be any information for a private function.