# (windows) raw write to file without involving win32api

Tags: windows, winapi, assembly, file-io

I would like to know if there is an option, and if so - how exactly, to be able to write raw bytes to a file without using WIN32API file handling calls, while in Windows.

I tried to use a stright-forward approach using x86asm direct file calls, but without success in the meantime.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: No matter what you do, it will eventually make a win32 API call.

Comment: The only way I see is calling the appropriate syscalls, but see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2489975/221786).

Comment: @MarkRansom: not strictly true, it's actually the NT API that everything (including the Win32 API) uses.  See Igor's answer.  For most purposes the distinction isn't relevant, but FWIW.

Comment: By "x86asm direct file calls" do you mean IBM PC BIOS calls, int 13h, or perhaps MS-DOS calls, int 21h?  You can't do anything like that from a Windows application.

Comment: @isso I want to test it's efficiency over win32api

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the [native API](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?id=91) from ntdll or even direct syscalls (int 2eh or systenter instruction), but it's quite tricky - you need to use kernel-style filenames, for one.

Comment: +1, but the OP should note that using the native API instead of the Win32 API doesn't usually gain you anything very useful.  For example, the same locking and security rules apply.

Comment: Igor,@HarryJohnston thanks, is native api is passing through win32api on the background or does it take it's own way to conduct file writing?

Comment: It's the other way around: Win32 APIs (kernel32) use native ones (ntdll) to do their work. But in the end, everything ends up in the kernel.

Comment: What does a "kernel-style filename" look like?

Comment: @Melab: https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.be/2016/02/the-definitive-guide-on-win32-to-nt.html

Answer (score 2):

Before answering your question let me mention that writing to a file using API in Windows consists of following (simplified) stages:

1. You call `WriteFile` (kernel32.dll)
2. `WriteFile` calls `NtWriteFile` (ntdll.dll)
3. `NtWriteFile` calls `SYSENTER` and operation proceeds to kernel mode
4. In kernel mode `NtWriteFile` function of Ntoskrnl.exe is called
5. This sends `IRP_MJ_WRITE` to file system driver
6. File system driver determines which sectors should be written and passes to storage driver
7. Storage driver sends a command to the hard drive to actually write data to specified sectors
8. Hard drive writes the data

All operations 1 to 7 are very fast compared to 8 (unless you are working with a RAM drive or extremely fast SSD)

Method 1 - You can skip Step 1 easily (by calling `NtWriteFile`), and Step2 (by calling `SYSENTER` - not easy). However you will not gain any performance improvement, so no point in doing it. Consider `WriteFile` just a wrapper for those (I don't think you are after eliminating one extra function call).

Method 2 - you can find out which sectors the file occupies and write to them directly (effectively skipping all steps down to Step 7). To do that you will need to open and lock the volume, find the clusters that the target file occupies by `FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS` call, and call `WriteFile` on volume handle.
But it will be unfair comparison, because file system driver not only writes to the data sectors, but also updates file system metadata when you call WriteFile.

Bottom line is - "Testing efficiency over win32 API" doesn't make much sense. You can skip some of the stuff that OS does, but either won't give you any difference in speed (method 1), or there will be unfair comparison (method2).

Comment: +1.  Another set of options involve writing a device driver so that your code is running in kernel mode.  Yet another set involve writing your code (or part of it) for the BIOS and running it outside of Windows altogether.  However, I doubt that any of these options would allow anyone to measure anything very useful.