# How do I write a syscall in x86 assembly for Windows?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, system-calls

I need to do a system call (syscall) in x86 assembly code that targets the Windows platform.

On Linux, I would just do something like `int 0x80`, but this doesn't work on Windows. What should the code look like to do a syscall on Windows?

(I am using AT&T syntax and writing 64-bit code, if it matters, but the answer should be the same for Intel syntax and 32-bit code.)

Comment: You will want to call WinAPI functions calls rather than making system calls directly.

Comment: I find it very hard to believe that we do not have one already, but I haven't been able to find a duplicate target for this question. It gets asked pretty often, so maybe we should consider turning this one into a canonical question? Anyone with more intimate knowledge of the x86 tag than me know of one that I'm missing? I did find [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489889) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21074334), but they are too focused on the NT Native (undocumented) APIs, which are irrelevant to the basic question of translating *NIX syscalls to Windows.

Comment: BTW, for 64-bit code on Linux you should be using the 64-bit ABI via `syscall`, not the 32-bit ABI via `int $0x80`, since it clobbers r8-r15, truncates your pointers to 32-bit, and uses the 32-bit version of any structs.  See links in the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for the calling convention and syscall numbers for `syscall`.  (i.e. look in unistd_64.h)

Answer (score 0):

Windows don't allow you to use interrupts like you use on DOS or Linux. You need to call WinAPI or C library instead. On 32-bit operating systems you have NTVDM, that's virtual machine for DOS apps, that allows you to use `int 21h`. Note that programs that access disk at low level (using these interrupts) can be marked as a false positive. This is example call to windows function without using interrputs (altrough assembly on Windows is nonsense):

```
global  _main
    extern  _printf

    section .text
_main:
    push    message
    call    _printf
    add     esp, 4
    ret
message:
    db  'Hello, World', 10, 0
```

Comment: *"altrough assembly on Windows is nonsense"* What does that mean?