# C++ asm insertion falls with int command

Tags: c++, assembly, g++, inline-assembly

I'm doing homework and trying to read keys from keyboard. I tried to use `16h` interrupt and started with this code

```
int main(){
    char key, shiftKey(2);
    asm ("movb %1, %%al;"
         "int $0x16;"
         "movb %%al, %0;"
    :"=r"(key)
    :"r"(shiftKey)
    :"%al"
    );
    std::cout << int(key);
}
```

Assembly algorithm is:

1. pass function number (02) to `al` register `movb 2, al`
2. call interruption `int 16h`
3. `al` now should have mask of all keys like shift, capslock etc.

This code crashes with `Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)`. So I have no proper info what have I done wrong.

Comment: Seems you are trying to compile this under Windows with G++? `int $0x16` is a BIOS call that is not available under Windows.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Yes, you are right. Do you have any suggestions about other interruptions?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are really trying to do or how low level you are going but maybe something like: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getch-getwch?view=vs-2017

Comment: @MichaelPetch Assembly is the target. I use C++ only for output detailed info. You also can post your mark as an answer. It really is.

Comment: The only stable system-call ABI on Windows is through DLL functions, not `int` or `syscall` directly.  [Windows system calls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21074334).  You can call DLL functions from asm, but I wouldn't recommend making function calls from *inline* asm.  It's hard to get right.  Better to write your whole program in asm, or whole functions at least.  (Use a debugger if you want to see values of things while running instead of debug-print).  GNU C inline asm is very unforgiving.

Comment: Ok. It's more clear now. Thank you.