# Why does the golang.org/x/sys package encourage the use of the syscall package it's meant to replace?

Tags: go

I have read some Go code making use of `syscall` for low-level interaction with the underlying OS (e.g. Linux or Windows).

I wanted to make  use of the same package  for native Windows development, but reading its documentation says it's deprecated in favor of `golang/x/sys`:

```
$ go doc syscall
package syscall // import "syscall"

Package syscall contains an interface to the low-level operating system
primitives.

...

Deprecated: this package is locked down. Callers should use the
corresponding package in the golang.org/x/sys repository instead. That is
also where updates required by new systems or versions should be applied.
See https://golang.org/s/go1.4-syscall for more information.
```

Now, reading the documentation for `golang/x/sys` and inspecting its code, it relies heavily on and encourages the use of the `syscall` package:

https://github.com/golang/sys/blob/master/windows/svc/example/beep.go

```
package main

import (
    "syscall"
)

var (
    beepFunc = syscall.MustLoadDLL("user32.dll").MustFindProc("MessageBeep")
)

func beep() {
    beepFunc.Call(0xffffffff)
}
```

and

https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/windows#example-LoadLibrary

```
...
r, _, _ := syscall.Syscall(uintptr(proc), 0, 0, 0, 0)
...
```

Why does `golang/x/sys` rely and encourage the use of the package it's meant to replace?

Answer (score 7):

Disclaimer: I'm pretty new to Go specifically (though not to low-level OS programming).  Still, the path here seems clear.

Go, as an ecosystem—not just the language itself, but all the various libraries as well—tries<sup>1</sup> to be portable.  But direct system calls are pretty much *not* portable at all.  So there is some tension here automatically.

In order to do anything useful, the Go runtime needs various services *from* the operating system, such as creating OS-level threads, sending and receiving signals, opening files and network connections, and so on.  Many of these operations can be, and have been, abstracted away from *how it is done on operating systems A, B, and C* to *generic concepts supported by most or all OSes*.  These abstractions build on the actual mechanisms in the various OSes.

They may even do this in layers internally.  A look at the [Go source for the `os` package](https://golang.org/src/os/), for instance, shows `file.go`, `file_plan9.go`, `file_posix.go`, `file_unix.go`, and `file_windows.go` source files.  The top of [`file_posix.go`](https://golang.org/src/os/file_posix.go) showss a `+build` directive:

```
// Copyright 2009 The Go Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style
// license that can be found in the LICENSE file.

// +build aix darwin dragonfly freebsd js,wasm linux nacl netbsd openbsd solaris windows
```

Clearly this code itself is *not* completely portable, but the routines it implements for `os`, which are wrapped by the `os.File` abstraction, suffice for all POSIX-conformant systems.  That reduces the amount of code that has to go in the Unix/Linux-specific `files_unix.go` file for instance.

To the extent that OS-level operations can be wrapped into more-abstract, more-portable operations, then, the various built-in Go packages do this.  You don't need to know whether there's a different system call for opening a device-file vs a text-file vs a binary-file, for instance, or a long pathname vs a short one: you just call `os.Create` or `os.Open` and it does any work necessary behind the scenes.

This whole idea just doesn't fly with system calls.  A Linux system call to create a new UID namespace has no Windows equivalent.<sup>2</sup>  A Windows `WaitForMultipleObjects` system call has no real equivalent on Linux.  The low level details of a stat/lstat call differ from one system to another, and so on.

In early versions of Go, there was some attempt to paper over this with the `syscall` package.  But the link you quoted—https://golang.org/s/go1.4-syscall—describes this attempt as, if not *failed*, at least *overstretched*.  The last word in the "problems" section is "issues".

The proposal at this same link says that the `syscall` package is to be frozen (or mostly frozen) as of Go 1.4: don't put new features into it.  But the features that *are* in it are sufficient to *implement* the new, experimental `golang.org/x/sys/*` packages, or at least some of them.  There's no harm in the experimental package borrowing the existing, formally-deprecated `syscall` package if that does what the experimental new package needs.

Things in `golang.org/x/` are experimental: feel free to use them, but be aware that there are no compatibility promises across version updates, unlike things in the standard packages.  So, to answer the last line of your question:

> Why does `golang/x/sys` rely [on] and encourage the use of the package it's meant to replace?

It *relies on* `syscall` because that's fine.  It *doesn't* "encourage the use of" `syscall` at all though.  It just *uses* it when that's sufficient.  Should that become insufficient, for whatever reason, it will stop relying on it.

Answering a question you didn't ask (but I did): suppose you want Unix-specific `stat` information about a file, such as its inode number.  You have a choice:

```
info, err := os.Stat(path) // or os.Lstat(path), etc
if err != nil { ... handle error ... }
raw, ok := info.Sys().(*syscall.Stat_t)
if !ok { ... do whatever is appropriate ... }
inodeNumber := raw.Ino
```

or:

```
var info unix.Stat
err := unix.Stat(path, &info) // or unix.Lstat, etc
if err != nil { ... handle error ... }
inodeNumber := unix.Ino
```

The advantage to the first block of code is that you get all the *other* (portable) information about the file—its mode and size and time-stamps, for instance.  You maybe do, maybe don't get the inode number; the `!ok` case tells you whether you did.  The primary disadvantage here is that it takes more code to do this.

The advantage to the second block of code is that it says just what you mean.  You either get all the information from the `stat` call, or none of it.  The disadvantages are obvious:

- it only works on Unix-ish systems, and
- it uses an experimental package, whose behavior might change.

So it's up to you which of these matters more to you.

---

<sup>1</sup>Either this is a metaphor, or I've just anthropomorphized this.  There's an old rule: Don't anthropomorphize computers, they hate that!

<sup>2</sup>A Linux UID namespace maps from UIDs inside a container to UIDs outside the container.  That is, inside the container, a file might be owned by UID 1234.  If the file is in a file system that is also mounted outside the container, that file can be owned by a different owner, perhaps 5678.  Changing the ownership on either "side" of the container makes the change in that side's namespace; the change shows up on the other side as the result of mapping, or reverse-mapping, the ID through the namespace mapping.

(This same trick also works for NFS UID mappings, for instance.  The Docker container example above is just one use, but probably the most notable one these days.)

Comment: Thank you for an excellent answer. I think it’s OK that the new `golang.org/x/sys` package relies on `syscall`, but users of former package should not. Also, what do you mean by system call on Windows? That OS has no system calls but only DLL’s with APIs? Are you referring to a specific DLL?

Comment: Windows definitely does have system calls. You may use a DLL to abstract them, but internally, they have OS level calls.

Comment: and you would use interrupts, just like for Linux, to call those system calls, with the system call number provided in a register? It's interesting that I've never seen a single example of calling Windows system call directly.

Comment: They definitely exist: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21074334/windows-system-calls for instance. The actual syscall numbers change from release to release, which is one reason not to use `int` instructions. Note that in the go runtime, the low level call has to be done from a separate stack, not from the normal goroutine stack. The goroutine must be locked to a thread and the thread cannot be used for other goroutines while the syscall runs. The `syscall` package provides the shims needed here.