# Win64 and Linux-x86_64 Calling Convention Unused registers modified or not

Tags: assembly, x86-64, system-calls, calling-convention

I have some important questions about calling convention in linux-x86_64 and win64.
I search too many places, but I have not found the answer of my questions !!!
I don't think my question is duplicated, so please read it first.

In linux-x86_64 we work with syscalls ...
**linux-x86_64 syscall calling convention is:**

```
RDI -> first parameter
RSI -> second parameter
RDX -> third parameter
R10 -> fourth parameter
R8  -> fifth parameter
R9  -> sixth parameter
R11 -> ... (for all syscalls)
RCX -> ... (for all syscalls)
RAX -> return
```

**Now, my questions about linux-x86_64:**

**Question 1:** If one syscall (for example, '`sys_write`') takes 3 parameters (`RDI,RSI,RDX`), what about other parameter registers? Yes this syscall has only 3 parameters but will it use other parameter registers too (for other usage like inside process and ...) ? I mean, if I call `sys_write` and I have something in `R10` register, will `R10` value remain 100% unchanged after the syscall ? This syscall has no fourth parameter, so I think everything inside R10 or R8 or R9 will remain unchanged ... correct ? Am I right ?

**Question 2:** For example, `sys_mkdir` ... If I have to call `sys_mkdir` 3 times (one after another), Is this way correct ?

```
mov eax, 83
mov rdi, .filename
mov esi, 0766o
syscall

mov eax, 83
mov rdi, .filename2
syscall            ; no (mov esi, 0766o) anymore because ESI is equal to 0766o from last syscall

mov eax, 83
mov rdi, .filename3
syscall            ; no (mov esi, 0766o) anymore because ESI is equal to 0766o from last syscall
```

**Here, i just not updated `ESI` anymore ... since I think `syscall` keeps parameter registers unchanged. Am I right?**

---

**Now Win64, Win64 Calling convention is:**

```
RCX -> first parameter
RDX -> second parameter
R8  -> third parameter
R9  -> fourth parameter
... (Stack)
```

Question 1: Here, my question about win64 calling convention is the same as the first question about linux-x86_64. if, for example, I call Some function with only 1 argument, (for example `ExitProcess`) ... will other parameter registers value remains unchanged? Or windows will use other parameter registers too and my value inside them will change ?

Comment: For Linux, this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-and-user-space-f.  `syscall` overwrites `rcx` and `r11`, and leaves the return value in `rax`.  All other registers, including those in which you passed arguments, remain unchanged.  The Windows part is really a separate question and I think it ought to be in a separate post.

Comment: Note that (again on Linux) `syscall` has a different convention than ordinary function calls, for which only `rbx, rbp, rsp, r12-r15` remain unchanged and everything else may be overwritten.

Comment: @NateEldredge but what about the second question in linux part?

Comment: Read again what I wrote above: " All other registers, **including those in which you passed arguments**, remain unchanged." So in your Question 2, `esi` will keep the value `0766o` throughout the multiple system calls.  (Still, readers of your code may not remember that, so it'd be wise to add comments to point it out.)

Comment: @NateEldredge true. In windows (x64), it changes the parameter registers values unfortunately (kernel32 functions ...) ... your answer was useful. Thank you

Comment: Better to ask two separate questions in two separate posts -- works better for this Q&A format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A registers's status as [call-preserved or call-clobbered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024672/what-registers-are-preserved-through-a-linux-x86-64-function-call) never depends on the number of args actually passed by the caller and/or expected by the callee, in any calling convention for any ISA I've looked at, and certainly not any of the standard ones on x86.

But yes the calling conventions for raw system calls are different from those for functions, even for presumably thin wrapper functions.

All standard user-space function calling conventions have all the arg-passing registers (and stack slots) as call-clobbered.  So if your asm uses `call`, that's what you need to expect.

The system-calling conventions on mainstream OSes preserves all registers (except the return value).  (But on x86-64, only after `syscall` itself overwrites RCX and R11, [because that happens before the kernel gets control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47983371/why-do-x86-64-linux-system-calls-modify-rcx-and-what-does-the-value-mean).)  If you directly use `syscall` or `int 0x80` or whatever, that's what you should expect.

Note that Windows does *not* have a stable system-call ABI across kernel versions and doesn't document the raw system calls, so in normal Windows code you're always making DLL function calls, never raw system calls.  [People have reverse-engineered the system calls for different Windows versions, though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21074334/windows-system-calls).

MacOS also doesn't *officially* have a stable/documented syscall ABI, but in practice Darwin basically does, at least for the normal POSIX open/read/write/close/exit calls that toy programs use.

- [What registers are preserved through a linux x86-64 function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024672/what-registers-are-preserved-through-a-linux-x86-64-function-call)
- [What are the calling conventions for UNIX & Linux system calls (and user-space functions) on i386 and x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-and-user-space-f)
- https://packagecloud.io/blog/the-definitive-guide-to-linux-system-calls/
- [Where is the x86-64 System V ABI documented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133812/where-is-the-x86-64-system-v-abi-documented)
- [Windows system calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21074334/windows-system-calls)