# Why is my NASM assembly not outputting to the console?

Tags: windows, assembly, nasm

Assuming I hate myself and want to avoid external libraries as much as possible, I am trying to write hello world assembly. From what little I understand, in Windows we should link with the kernel32.dll and output from that. Any ideas why my code is not outputting?

code:

```
extern ExitProcess
extern WriteFile

section .text
   global Start     ;must be declared for linker (ld)
    
Start:              ;tells linker entry point
   mov  rdx,len     ;message length
   mov  rcx,msg     ;message to write
   mov  rbx,1       ;file descriptor (stdout)
   mov  rdx,4       ;system call number (sys_write)
   int  WriteFile       ;call kernel
    
   mov  rax,1       ;system call number (sys_exit)
   int  ExitProcess      ;call kernel

section .data
msg db 'Hello, world!', 0xa  ;string to be printed
len equ $ - msg     ;length of the string
```

instructions ran:

`nasm -f win64 -o hello_world.obj hello_world.asm`

`golink hello_world.obj kernel32.dll`

`hello_world.exe`

no errors or warnings on running the commands.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://bitcodersblog.wordpress.com/2017/05/10/win32-in-nasm-part-1/amp/ there are sveral examples, just go to: Take Three

Comment: That looks like the 32-bit Linux system-calling convention (for use with `int 0x80`), and then you overwrite the length in RDX with a call number.  And execute an `int imm8` with an interrupt number that depends on an address.  Even as `-felf32` under Linux this wouldn't work (although it's close, but see [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46087730)), and it definitely won't work on any other OS.  Definitely not Windows; [Windows system calls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21074334)

Comment: I'm really surprised your linker doesn't warn when filling in an 8-bit immediate (that you're using as an interrupt number!) with a 64-bit absolute address.  But yeah `nasm -fwin64` does actually assemble without warning.  objdump -drwC shows it assembled to a .obj with a placeholder imm8=0: `cd 00    int  0x0   1a: IMAGE_REL_AMD64_ADDR32      WriteFile`

Comment: Did you maybe mean to `call  WriteFile`?  Because that would be the correct thing to do.  (Or `call [rel WriteFile]` to go through the dynamic linker's function pointer.)  Except of course WriteFile follows the Windows x64 calling convention, so those aren't the right registers for args, and it doesn't take a Unix file descriptor number like `1`, it takes a file *handle*.

Comment: Basically, you need to throw out your entire code except for the `extern` lines and the `.data` section, because all of it is completely wrong for Windows x64.  It looks like you started with a 32-bit Linux example, and changed the wrong things about it.