# Difference in ABI between x86_64 Linux functions and syscalls

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, x86-64, system-calls, abi

The [x86_64 SysV ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation.html)'s function calling convention defines integer argument #4 to be passed in the `rcx` register.  The Linux kernel syscall ABI, on the other hand, uses `r10` for that same purpose. All other arguments are passed in the same registers for both functions and syscalls.

This leads to some strange things. Check out, for example, the implementation of `mmap` in glibc for the x32 platform (for which the same discrepancy exists):

```
00432ce0 <__mmap>:
  432ce0:       49 89 ca                mov    %rcx,%r10
  432ce3:       b8 09 00 00 40          mov    $0x40000009,%eax
  432ce8:       0f 05                   syscall
```

So all register are already in place, except we move `rcx` to `r10`.

I am wondering why not define the syscall ABI to be the same as the function call ABI, considering that they are already so similar.

Comment: In [another ABI answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35619528/224132), I dug up some links to amd64 mailing-list posts from AMD architects and Linux kernel developers before the first AMD64 silicon was released.  There's some interesting stuff there, like the experimental results (from compiling SPECint and looking at code-size and number of instructions) that led to the x86-64 SysV ABI's choices for which register to use for what.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`syscall` instruction](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SYSCALL.html) is intended to provide a quicker method of entering Ring-0 in order to carry out a system call. This is meant to be an improvement over the old method, which was to raise a software interrupt (`int 0x80` on Linux).

Part of the reason the instruction is faster is because it does not change memory, or even change `rsp` to point at a kernel stack. Unlike a software interrupt, where the CPU is forced to allow the OS to resume operation without clobbering anything, for this command the CPU is allowed to assume the software is aware that something is happening here.

In particular, `syscall` stores two parts of the user-space state in registers. The `RIP` to return to after the call is stored in `rcx`, and the flags are stored in `R11` ([because RFLAGS is masked with a kernel-supplied value before entry to the kernel](http://www.x86-64.org/pipermail/discuss/2000-October/001019.html)). This means that both those registers are clobbered by the instruction.

Since they are clobbered, the syscall ABI uses another register instead of `rcx`, hence the use of `r10` for the 4th argument.

`r10` is a natural choice, since [in the x86-64 SystemV ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation_folder/abi.pdf#page=22) it's not used for passing function args, and functions don't need to preserve their caller's value of `r10`.  So a syscall wrapper function can `mov %rcx, %r10` without any save/restore.  This wouldn't be possible with any other register, for 6-arg syscalls and the SysV ABI's function calling convention.

---

BTW, the 32-bit system call ABI is also accessible with `sysenter`, which requires cooperation between user-space and kernel-space to allow returning to user-space after a `sysenter`.  (i.e. storing some state in user-space before running `sysenter`).  This is higher performance than `int 0x80`, but awkward.  Still, glibc uses it (by jumping to user-space code in the vdso pages that the kernel maps into the address space of every process).

AMD's `syscall` is another approach to the same idea as Intel's `sysenter`: to make entry/exit from the kernel less expensive by not preserving absolutely everything.

Comment: It's more subtle than just replacing a couple stores with register-register moves.  It doesn't change `rsp` to point to the kernel stack, so there would be no sane place to push anything it wanted to save.  Kernel code at the entry point has to do that itself.  (using `swapgs` enables `[gs:absolute_address]` to access per-task kernel data).  The CPU doesn't also internally keep a kernel stack pointer to use for `syscall`, just a saved `gs` value.  I think this is where the implementation-complexity reduction comes from.  (And that `swapgs` is a separate instruction).

Comment: The part about C/C++ not using `r10` is meaningless. The kernel is not allowed to assume which language is performing the call.

Comment: I found a way to word it which doesn't mention static chain pointers at all, while still being completely accurate and not ignoring them (I think :).  They're not relevant for wrapper functions, and are a distraction from the point here (esp. since most people have never heard of them, and I don't even know exactly what they are).  I also cleaned up the comment thread.

Answer (score 6):

AMD's `syscall` clobbers the `rcx` register, thus `r10` is used instead.

Comment: And `r10` is a pure scratch register: not used for function arg-passing, and not call-preserved.  This lets other wrapper functions like dynamic-linker stubs use it as a temporary and still be able to tail-call with a `jmp` instead of a `call` / `pop` / `ret`.  So `r10` is a good choice for syscalls.  `syscall` / `sysret` also use r11.

Comment: Oops, I was thinking of `r11`.  The ABI says `r10` is used for passing a "static chain pointer".  C/C++ don't use that, so in practice `r10` is also a pure scratch register.

Comment: What is meaning of "clobber" in this context?

Comment: @tuket: It means the register is overwritten without saving/restoring the old value.  In the same sense as GCC inline asm's "clobber list", and see [What are callee and caller saved registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56178078) re: call-preserved vs. call-clobbered registers as good terminology for what people sometimes call non-volatile vs. volatile in a calling-convention.