# Why Assembly x86_64 syscall parameters are not in alphabetical order like i386

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, cpu-registers, calling-convention

There is that one question that troubles me.

So ... Why in **x86_32** the **parameters** are passed in registers that I feel are in **alphabetically** (`eax`, `ecx`, `edx`, `esi`) and **ranked** order (`esi`, `edi`, `ebp`)

```
+---------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| syscall | arg0 | arg1 | arg2 | arg3 | arg4 | arg5 |
+---------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|   %eax  | %ebx | %ecx | %edx | %esi | %edi | %ebp |
+---------+------+------+------+------+------+------+

section .text
    global _start
_start:
    mov eax, 1     ; x86_64 opcode for sys_exit
    mov ebx, 0     ; first argument
    int 0x80
```

While in **x86_64** syscall's parameters are passed in registers that look a little bit **randomly** arranged:

```
+---------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| syscall | arg0 | arg1 | arg2 | arg3 | arg4 | arg5 |
+---------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|   %rax  | %rdi | %rsi | %rdx | %r10 | %r8  | %r9  |
+---------+------+------+------+------+------+------+

section .text
    global _start
_start:
    mov eax, 1     ; x86_64 opcode for sys_exit
    mov edi, 0     ; first argument
    syscall
```

Did they do that for a specific reason? Am I not seeing something here?

Comment: In x86-64, it matches the function-calling convention so syscall wrapper functions are light weight.  In i386, IDK why it uses that inconvenient setup (`ebx` is call-preserved, so almost every syscall wrapper needs to save/restore ebx.)

Comment: @PeterCordes And the function calling convention was designed to reduce the amount of register shuffling when implementing `memcpy` with `rep movsb` among other things.

Comment: function-calling convention? Maybe I'll sound like a rookie, maybe because I am ... but what is a function-calling convention? Is that an Assembly thing?

Comment: My answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429398/why-does-windows64-use-a-different-calling-convention-from-all-other-oses-on-x86/35619528#35619528 has some history about how the x86-64 SysV ABI was designed (including links to mailing list archives from Jan Hubicka, who did the designing.)

Comment: @ApostolisAnastasiou: Normally you'd just say "the calling convention", but we need to distinguish between the calling convention for functions, and the calling convention for system calls.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-on-i386-and-x86-6 for info on both.  (This question could maybe be a duplicate of either this link or the one in my previous comment...)

Comment: @PeterCordes So, If I understood, the reason behind the registers used is their Electronical Structure and their mechanical operation? No one is specifically referring to it, but Jan Habicka here: http://web.archive.org/web/20140414124645/http://www.x86-64.org/pipermail/discuss/2000-November/001257.html states that other registers produced less amount of code? How can that be? Since 5 minutes before I thought all registers were the same but they were used differently because of a convention. Now all things changed for me ...

Comment: I put my reply to this comment into my answer with an edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The x86-64 System V ABI was designed to minimize instruction-count (and to some degree code-size) in SPECint as compiled by the version of gcc that was current before the first AMD64 CPUs were sold.  See [this answer for some history and list-archive links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429398/why-does-windows64-use-a-different-calling-convention-from-all-other-oses-on-x86/35619528#35619528).

> Since 5 minutes before I thought all registers were the same but they were used differently because of a convention. Now all things changed for me

x86-64 is not fully orthogonal.  Some instructions implicitly use specific registers.  e.g. `push` implicitly uses `rsp` as the stack pointer, `shl edx, cl` is only usable with a shift count in `cl` (until BMI2 `shlx`).

More rarely used: widening `mul rdi` does `rdx:rax = rax*rdi`.  The rep-string instructions implicitly use RDI, RSI, and RCX, although they're often not worth using.

It turns out that choosing the arg-passing registers so that functions that passed their args to memcpy could inline it as `rep movs` was useful in the metric Jan Hubicka was using, thus `rdi` and `rsi` were chosen as the first two args.  But that leaving `rcx` unused until the 4th arg was better, because `cl` is needed for variable-count shift.  (And most functions don't happen to use their 3rd arg as a shift count.)  (Probably older GCC versions inlined `memcpy` or `memset` as `rep movs` more aggressively; it's usually not worth it vs. SIMD for small arrays these days.)

---

**The x86-64 System V ABI uses almost the same calling convention for functions as it does for system calls**.  This is not a coincidence: it means the implementation for a libc wrapper function like `mmap` can be:

```
mmap:
    mov  r10, rcx       ; syscall destroys rcx and r11; 4th arg passed in r10 for syscalls
    mov  eax, __NR_mmap
    syscall

    cmp  rax, -4096
    ja  .set_errno_and_stuff
    ret
```

This is a tiny advantage, but there's really no reason *not* to do this.  It also saves a few instructions inside the kernel setting up the arg-passing registers before dispatching to the C implementation of the system call in the kernel.  (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087730/what-happens-if-you-use-the-32-bit-int-0x80-linux-abi-in-64-bit-code/46087731#46087731) for a look at some kernel side of system call handling.  Mostly about the `int 0x80` handler, but I think I mentioned the 64-bit `syscall` handler and that it dispatches to a table of functions directly from asm.)

The `syscall` instruction itself [destroys RCX and R11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47983371/why-do-x86-64-linux-system-calls-modify-rcx-and-what-does-the-value-mean) (to save user-space RIP and RFLAGS without needing microcode to set up the kernel stack) so the conventions can't be identical unless the user-space convention avoided RCX and R11.  But RCX is a handy register whose low half can be used without a REX prefix so that probably would have been worse than leaving it as a call-clobbered pure scratch like R11.  Also, the user-space convention uses R10 as a "static chain" pointer for languages with first-class nested functions (not C/C++).

Having the first 4 args able to avoid a REX prefix is probably best for overall code-size, and using RBX or RBP instead of RCX would be weird.  Having a couple call-preserved registers that don't need a REX prefix (EBX/EBP) is good.

See [What are the calling conventions for UNIX & Linux system calls on i386 and x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-on-i386-and-x86-6) for the function-call and system-call conventions.

---

**The i386 system call convention is the clunky and inconvenient one**: `ebx` is call-preserved, so almost every syscall wrapper needs to save/restore `ebx`, except for calls with no args like `getpid`.  (And for that you don't even need to enter the kernel, just call into the vDSO: see [**The Definitive Guide to Linux System Calls** (on x86)](https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2016/04/05/the-definitive-guide-to-linux-system-calls/) for more about vDSO and tons of other stuff.)

But the i386 function-calling convention passes all args on the stack, so glibc wrapper functions still need to `mov` every arg anyway.

Also note that the "natural" order of x86 registers is EAX, ECX, EDX, EBX, according to their numeric codes in machine code, and also the order that `pusha` / `popa` use.  See [Why are first four x86 GPRs named in such unintuitive order?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5121/why-are-first-four-x86-gprs-named-in-such-unintuitive-order).

Comment: Any clue why the `syscall` convention differs at 4th arg from the userland convention (`r10` vs `rcx`)? You make a good point about simple wrappers but they could be even faster except for this discrepancy which requires shuffling 1, 2 or 3 arguments for calls with 4, 5 or 6 arguments.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: The `syscall` instruction itself literally clobbers `rcx` and `r11` with the saved `RIP` and `RFLAGS` values.  It's a *very* minor factor in the choice of calling convention, so considerations like REX-needed high regs vs. no-REX registers like ecx outweighed it.  And if the convention had used `rbx` instead of `rcx` as an arg-passing/call-clobbered "low" reg, variable shifts would need to safe/restore it.  You also want some call-preserved low regs (RBP, and RBX because it's the "least special" low register, mainly CPUID / CMPXCHG16B (which didn't even exist originally))